# SimpleModal not showing content box on firefox and chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, simplemodal

i am using the SimpleModal JQuery plugin to show some content ( iframe with flash ).
Everything works just fine in IE , but when trying to open the modal in Chrome or Firefox,
only the faded overlay shows up, even due i can see with fiddler that the iframe content is loading.

i tried the solution on [SimpleModal containerCSS not working in firefox or chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238536/simplemodal-containercss-not-working-in-firefox-or-chrome)

and added units, but still with no luck.

The problem is the same as described here: [jQuery simplemodal not working well in Safari for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311346/jquery-simplemodal-not-working-well-in-safari-for-windows)
but for chrome and firefox, havent tested it on safari.

using "jquery-1.6.2.min","jquery.simplemodal-1.4.1"
here is my code:

```
// Apply click behaviour to game click
$('div.rGame').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<div></div>').load('/ajax/' + $(this).attr('data-g') + '/').modal( // AJAX
    {
    minHeight: "820px",
    minWidth: "800px",
    overlayClose: false,
    position: ["10", null],
    onOpen: function (dialog) {
        dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.hide();
            dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                dialog.data.slideDown('slow', function () {
                    MakeGamePage();
                });
            });
        });
    },
    onClose: function (dialog) {
        dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
                dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $.modal.close();
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested, i found a solution:

`position: ["10", null],`

should be `position: ["10px", null],`

i missed that ;)